# Why does this C++ function return a value?

Tags: c++, function, for-loop

Why does this code print out n-100?

```
    int hello(int n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n-100; i++)
        {
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
            int h = hello(12);
        cout << hello(12) << " " << h << endl;
    }
```

Yet, both of these function return garbage (2665092 and 0 respectively)

```
    int hello1(int n)
    {
          for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++);
    }


    int hello2(int n)
    {
         (n - 100);
    }
```

I compiled this code using g++ in the cygwin environment.

Comment: *"Why does this code print out n-100?"* It doesn't, I get `1 1`. :)

Comment: The return value is supposed to be stored somewhere, like in a register. If you don't set the return value, that register might contain something else, like a value you used recently.

Comment: @BoPersson ahh thank you, that makes a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are simply seeing the result of **undefined behaviour**.

Always compile with `-Wall -Werror` to prevent this kind of bug from creeping into your code.